# Incorrect value for stdio stream: WriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const barStream = fs.createWriteStream('bar');
const foo = spawn('foo', [], { stdio: ['ignore', barStream, 'inherit'] });
```

throws an error:

> Incorrect value for stdio stream: WriteStream

Doing this in reverse like `foo.stdout.pipe(barStream)` likely does the trick in some cases.

But why exactly `WriteStream` cannot be supplied as stdout stream? Is there a way to make `barStream` suitable for stdout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation for the `stdio` option](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio), emphasis mine:

> `<Stream>` object - Share a readable or writable stream that refers to a tty, file, socket, or a pipe with the child process. The stream's underlying file descriptor is duplicated in the child process to the fd that corresponds to the index in the stdio array. **Note that the stream must have an underlying descriptor (file streams do not until the 'open' event has occurred).**

So:

```
const barStream = fs.createWriteStream('bar');

barStream.on('open', () => {
    const foo = spawn('foo', [], { stdio: ['ignore', barStream, 'inherit'] });
    ⋮
});
```

I’ll admit that error message could definitely be more helpful.

Comment: Clear and simple. Thanks.

Comment: In async code, you can do `await events.once(barStream, 'open');` from the [Events module](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) after creating the write stream.