# in nodejs, spawn direct stdout and stderr to log file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my code:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn
var fs = require("fs")
var p = spawn("ls", ["prprpr"])
var log = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/prpr.log")
p.stdout.pipe(log)
p.stderr.pipe(log)
```

when i `cat /tmp/prpr.log`, it return empty, but when i redirect to process.stdout and process.stderr, it output error correctly

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn
var fs = require("fs")
var p = spawn("ls", ["prprpr"])
var log = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/prpr.log")
p.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
p.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
```

how to make spawn stdout and stderr to disk file?

my node version:

```
> roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/js/ro-evernote $ node -v
v7.3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

```
const child_process = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");
const out = fs.openSync("./stdout.log", "a");
const err = fs.openSync("./stderr.log", "a");
const child = child_process.spawn("ls", ["-alc"], {
  stdio: [process.stdin, out, err]
});
```

You just need to pass the file descriptors to the stdio (no need to create streams). There are a lot of flavors for this [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) - specifically take note of how `detached` and passing `'ignore'` for stdin impact how the child survives the parent process.

Keep in mind passing file descriptors is one of Node's only ways of IPC.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

when i use following another way to redirect stdout:

```
var fs = require("fs")
let log = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/prpr.log");
const child = require("child_process").spawn('ls', ["prprpr"], {stdio: [null, log, log]});
```

it will raise

```
TypeError: Incorrect value for stdio stream: WriteStream {
```

it's the reason why I cannot write to log

I find the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846696/incorrect-value-for-stdio-stream-writestream), WriteStream can writable when "open"

and use following code will work:

```
var fs = require("fs")
let log = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/prpr.log");
log.on("open", function () {
  const child = require("child_process").spawn('ls', ["prprpr"], {stdio: [null, log, log]});
})
```